# Posting spotify url to facebook no longer working

Tags: iphone, facebook, spotify

I used to have a working way of posting spotify songs perfectly to facebook.

They would appear like any other link shared from a mac or windows version of spotify.

Now, several months later.. I can only post links like www.domain.com, but I can no longer post links like http://open.spotify.com/track/4yLSpYlcO0jPPLTa3nW8zN

Can somebody try posting a link like the one above and see if it appears as a play icon with album art on their facebook for me? Im wondering if facebook has changed their API so that this is no longer possible? Im using FBGraph.

The result should look like this(like it worked earlier):

http://voteplay.no/fbspotify.png

However, now instead Im getting this error when using the spotify url:

Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

**UPDATE**

Code:

```
‎- (IBAction)facebookShare:(id)sender {

PartyQAppDelegate *delegate = (PartyQAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
facebook = [delegate facebook];

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {

facebook.sessionDelegate = delegate;

NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"read_stream", @"publish_stream",@"offline_access", nil];

[facebook authorize:permissions];

NSLog(@"SESSION NOT VALID!");

}else {

NSLog(@"SESSION VALID!");

NSString *trackurl = [self openSpotifyEncode:self.currentTrackPlaying];

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:trackurl, @"link",nil];

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

}

}

- (NSString *)openSpotifyEncode:(NSString *)string {

NSString *encodedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://open.spotify.com/track/%@", [string substringFromIndex:14]];

return encodedString;

}
```

---

I have resolved the error and do no longer need any help! Thank you for letting me know that it was still working.(Made be try harder to find the error).

The error was in the order of code in the appdelegate, but I still dont know why this would let me post all other links perfectly fine and not the spotify ones.

Comment: So you're posting to /feed - what parameter are you using for the URL - it should be 'link' as far as i know (i.e `link:http://open.spotify...`)

Comment: @Igy Yes, like show above. The code used to work with spotify links, but now only works with regular links. I thought that I would try posting longer regular links just to rule out that suddenly being an issue, but even those worked perfectly. Its only the spotify ones that dont work anymore. I have also triple-checked that the spotify url is valid.

Comment: I just tried with one of my apps, to /me/feed, with the URL in the link parameter, with and without a message and it worked OK: http://i.imgur.com/Tb6Ye.png

Comment: @Igy We are using the same id for two different apps like explained in the IOS Get started tutorial. Can this be affecting the result somehow you think?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this by posting the link directly on Facebook, and via an Application. Both worked correctly and shows the image and meta data for the track. You can test it yourself using the Graph API Explorer tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

[image: Screenshot]

Make sure there isn't an issue with the code elsewhere. I see that you are asking for the `offline_access` permission, which is in the process of being deprecated by Facebook.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for helping :)! I have now removed that permission now but still the same result. My friend has been changing the developers.facebook.com -> App. Is there any settings there that can be causing the trouble :) ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how Facebook renders the link from your application?

Comment: Regular link or Spotify link you mean?

Comment: The spotify link since that is the one you are having issues with. Both if the issue is affecting normal links too.

Comment: The issue is ONLY effecting spotify links. Using spotify links gives the error above and doesnt get posted at all. Regular links post just fine.

Comment: I'm stumped. Have you double checked your App Settings? Try posting using the app as a developer and see if FB give you more details on the error.

Comment: Still no error code im affraid. We are using the same id for two different apps like explained in the IOS Get started tutorial. Can this be affecting the result somehow you think?